# Windows unable to install dlib

Tags: python, window, dlib

I'm trying to install Dlib on my `Windows 8.1` with this command:

```
python -m pip install dlib
```

After I run it I get this error log:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:


    command: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys,
 setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\YOSIFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\T
emp\\pip-install-j8dowk8r\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\YOSIFA~
1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8dowk8r\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tok
enize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'
"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --re
cord 'C:\Users\YOSIFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6s43j4hs\install-record.tx
t' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\YOSIFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8dowk8r\dlib\
    Complete output (66 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19
:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\YOSIFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-instal
l-j8dowk8r\dlib\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\YOSIFA~1\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8dowk8r\dlib\build\lib.win32-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUT
ABLE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECT
ORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\YOSIFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8dowk8r\dlib\build
\lib.win32-3.7'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 8.1 to target Windows 6.3.9600.
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.22.27905.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.22.27905.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Stu
dio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Stu
dio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual S
tudio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual S
tudio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.22.27905/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    -- Found PythonInterp: C:/Program Files (x86)/Python37-32/python.exe (found
version "3.7.4")
    CMake Error at C:/Users/wwwwwwwww/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-j8dowk8
r/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:122 (message):
      Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      C:/Users/wwwwwwwww/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-j8dowk8r/dlib/dlib/e
xternal/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
      C:/Users/wwwwwwwww/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-j8dowk8r/dlib/dlib/e
xternal/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "C:/Users/wwwwwwwww/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-j8dowk8r/dli
b/build/temp.win32-3.7/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\YOSIFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8dowk8r\dlib\setup
.py", line 261, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development',
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__in
it__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148,
 in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966,
 in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985,
 in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\comm
and\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\install.py"
, line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313,
in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985,
 in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py",
line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313,
in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985,
 in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\YOSIFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8dowk8r\dlib\setup
.py", line 135, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\YOSIFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j8dowk8r\dlib\setup
.py", line 172, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in
check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\YOSIFA~1\\AppD
ata\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8dowk8r\\dlib\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_O
UTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\YOSIFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8dowk8r\
\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pyth
on37-32\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\YOSIF
A~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8dowk8r\\dlib\\build\\lib.win32-3.7']' r
eturned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-
32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\U
sers\\YOSIFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8dowk8r\\dlib\\setup.py'"'"';
 __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\YOSIFA~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j8dowk8r\\
dlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.r
ead().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file_
_, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\YOSIFA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
record-6s43j4hs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compil
e Check the logs for full command output.
```

I did install Python 64 bit, Any idea what can be the problem? Why I'm still getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Dlib is support with **python 3.6 to 3.7.0** version s.Try to install the dlib in anaconda prompt by following command.,

step 1:
        conda create -n env_name python=3.7.0

step 2:
       conda activate env_name

step 3:
       conda install -c conda-forge dlib=19.17

-c is stands for channel, conda-forge is one of channels.

you can find all supported packages for conda's in this link https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/

Anaconda is available from, https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section

conda instruction are, https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf